# Laravel AJAX not posting image

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms, image

I have a form that includes an option to upload a file. All the data from the form is sent to the controller when the form is submitted apart from the image. As you can see AJAX is posting all the parameters but not the image:

_token=dNyEbbLUQC8EvAWS0excGult93epW2anNVp35mfp&VideoTitle=test&VideoStrapline=test&VideoURL=test&editordata=%3Cp%3Etest%3C%2Fp%3E&VideoTags=test&MetaActName=test&MetaRegion=England%20-%20Midlands&MetaGenre=Alternative&MetaVenue=test***NOTHING HERE FROM IMAGE UPLOAD***

```
...
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="VideoCoverPhoto">Cover image</label>
        <input id="VideoCoverPhoto" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="form-control" name="VideoCoverPhoto">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-submit-add-video">Add Video</button>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

    });
        $(".btn-submit-add-video").each(function(){
      $(this).on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let form = $(this).closest('form');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.successful);
            }
        });

        console.log(form.serialize());
    })
    });

</script>
```

Why is the uploaded image not being submitted with the data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your form has the **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute.
Then Use  FormDAta Object which is the modern and preferred way of uploading files through ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(form),
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.successful);
        }
 });
```